# PHP SOAP ws-security

Tags: php, soap, ws-security

I have to communicate with a web service written on .Net using SOAP. This web service requires ws-security authentication with certificate and user/password. Authentication is defined like this:

```
<security mode="Message">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None"  />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
</security>
```

Is there any library that implements ws-security for PHP? Or, may be, somewhere can be found a good example of how to implement this using PHP's SoapClient? All I found is a snippet that works only with `UserNameToken`:

```
$ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';

$token = new \stdClass();
$token->Username = new \SoapVar('<username>', XSD_STRING, null, null, null, $ns);
$token->Password = new \SoapVar('<password>', XSD_STRING, null, null, null, $ns);

$wsec = new \stdClass();
$wsec->UsernameToken = new \SoapVar($token, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, null, $ns);

$headers = new \SoapHeader($ns, 'Security', $wsec, true);

$this->soapClient = new \SoapClient('<wsdlurl>',array());

$this->soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
```

But service responds with

```
The security context token is expired or is not valid. The message was not processed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [NuSoap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140189/PHP-NuSOAP-Tutorial)

I used it many years ago, it was more advanced than the default php soap client. Especially when communicating cross platform

Comment: Sadly, NuSoap does not support WS-Security

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought it did :(

Comment: Something like https://code.google.com/p/wse-php/source/browse/soap-wsse.php will to the trick. It supports X509 keys etc.

Comment: Thanks for the improved answer :)